# Understanding how to find the Covariance of this poisson process

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

$N(t),t>0\quad$ is a poisson process with rate $\lambda$=2.5 and we need to solve $Cov[N(3),N(6)-N(1)]$

There is a worked example for this but it seems to be skipping some steps which is not obvious to me (mainly the first two steps, the variance part I follow), if somebody can help out it would be greatly appreciated:

$=Cov[N(3)-N(1),N(6)-N(1)]\\=Cov[N(3)-N(1),N(3)-N(1)]\\=Var[N(3)-N(1)]\\=Var[N(2)]\\=5$

Comment: What´s the meaning of $N(3), N(1),...$ ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers.

Comment: @callculus, I have edited the post, hopefully this makes it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$C:=\mathrm{Cov}[N(3),N(6)-N(1)]=\mathrm{Cov}[N(3)-N(1)+N(1), N(6)-N(1)]$$
The linearity of covariance leads to
$$C=\mathrm{Cov}[N(3)-N(1), N(6)-N(1)]+\underbrace{\mathrm{Cov}[N(1), N(6)-N(1)]}_{0}$$
The second summand equals to $0$ since $N(1)$ and $N(6)-N(1)$ are independent.

Do the same at the second step: $N(6)-N(1)=(N(6)-N(3))+(N(3)-N(1))$ and use independence.

Comment: You are welcome! If you wish, you can also consider the possibility to "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).